# Size of virtual memory in Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-memory, memory-management

On what basis the size of User and kernel virtual memory is decided in Linux? (32-bit, if that's relevant.) Is it configurable?

If we have 512 MB RAM What will be the size of user and kernel virtual address?

Comment: Is this a 32bit or 64bit version of linux?

Comment: You can configure the kernel/userspace address split with the  [*VMSPLIT*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig#n1427) options.  But that only affects virtual address space, not physical RAM.

Comment: If 32 bits then one fourth of virtual upper space is dedicated to kernel. The rest is dedicated to userspace.

Things change a lot for 64bit kernel: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html

Comment: Structure cannot explain in one line ,check https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/articles/l-kernel-memory-access/

Comment: My question is for 32 bit linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The available address space depends on the architecture. One limit is the amount of address space made available by the architecture itself. 64-bit architectures usually allow 64-bit pointers, and 32-bit architectures allow 32-bit pointers. The amount of addressable space can be limited by the architecture beyond these constraints, and the architecture can also impose a certain structure. On top of all that, the kernel applies its own decisions, and some of these are configurable.

On 32-bit x86, [five different setups](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.3/source/arch/x86/Kconfig#L1423) are possible:

- the default allocates 3GiB to userspace, and 1GiB to the kernel, and allows for nearly 1GiB of “low” physical memory — the split is at 0xC0000000;
- a variant 3G/1G split shifts the split down to allow for a full 1GiB of low memory — the split is at 0xB000000;
- the 2G/2G split allocates 2GiB to userspace, 2GiB to the kernel, and has two variants like the 3G/1G split — the split is at either 0x8000000 or 0x7800000;
- the 1G/3G split allocates 1GiB to userspace, 3GiB to the kernel — the split is at 0x4000000.

For a system with 512MiB of RAM, you should use the default 3G/1G split; userspace will have 3GiB of address space, and the kernel will have 1GiB.

On 64-bit x86, [two different setups are possible](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/x86/x86_64/mm.html), allowing either 128 TiB or 64 PiB of address space for both userspace and the kernel.

Other architectures have different setups.